# python clear content writing on same file

Tags: python

I am a newbie to python. I have a code in which I must write the contents again to my same file,but when I do it it clears my content.Please help to fix it.

How should I modify my code such that the contents will be written back on the same file?

My code:

```
import re

numbers = {}
with open('1.txt') as f,open('11.txt', 'w') as f1:
    for line in f:
        row = re.split(r'(\d+)', line.strip())
        words = tuple(row[::2])
        if words not in numbers:
            numbers[words] = [int(n) for n in row[1::2]]
        numbers[words] = [n+1 for n in numbers[words]]
        row[1::2] = map(str, numbers[words])

        indentation = (re.match(r"\s*", line).group())
        print (indentation + ''.join(row))
        f1.write(indentation + ''.join(row) + '\n')
```

Comment: Writing back text into the same file will leave you unhappy.

Comment: by modifying the code,i mean creating a new write file on same file name can be possible?

Comment: @adsqwqwe If you just need to append to the file, there is an answer for you. Otherwise you need to load the file into memory to modify it. Or you can load to a new temporary file and then rename it.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it's a bad idea to write over a file you're still processing (or change a data structure over which you are iterating). It can be done...but it requires much care, and there is little safety or restart-ability should something go wrong in the middle (an error, a power failure, etc.)

A better approach is to write a clean new file, then rename it to the old name. For example:

```
import re
import os

filename = '1.txt'
tempname = "temp{0}_{1}".format(os.getpid(), filename)
numbers = {}
with open(filename) as f, open(tempname, 'w') as f1:
    # ... file processing as before

os.rename(tempname, filename)
```

Here I've dropped filenames (both original and temporary) into variables, so they can be easily referred to multiple times or changed. This also prepares for the moment when you hoist this code into a function (as part of a larger program), as opposed to making it the main line of your program.

You don't strictly need the temporary name to embed the process id, but it's a standard way of making sure the temp file is uniquely named (`temp32939_1.txt` vs `temp_1.txt` or `tempfile.txt`, say).

It may also be helpful to create backups of the files as they were before processing. In which case, before the `os.rename(tempname, filename)` you can drop in code to move the original data to a safer location or a backup name. E.g.:

```
backupname = filename + ".bak"
os.rename(filename, backupname)

os.rename(tempname, filename)
```

While beyond the scope of this question, if you used a read-process-overwrite strategy frequently, it would be possible to create a separate module that abstracted these file-handling details away from your processing code. [Here is an example.](https://gist.github.com/jonathaneunice/30e21cffa3b3e7b61952)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
open('11.txt', 'a')
```

To append to the file instead of w for writing (a new or overwriting a file).

Comment: The asker doesn't want to append, they want to overwrite the existing file.

Comment: on append it will overwrite,and it will damage my file.is there any other way?

Comment: In that case, I suggest to write to another file and then remove the original file and copy the other (or whatever you exactly want; it's not 100% clear to me). But reading/writing to the same file is in general not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read and modify file in one time use "r+' mode.

```
f=file('/path/to/file.txt', 'r+')
content=f.read()
content=content.replace('oldstring', 'newstring') #for example change some substring in whole file
f.seek(0) #move to beginning of file
f.write(content)
f.truncate() #clear file conent "tail" on disk if new content shorter then old
f.close()
```

Comment: Reading and writing to the same file, as many people have said, is *not* a good idea and should not be encouraged.  Also, you don't actually write anything to the file here, so you've just obliterated everything.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me, that I forget `write()` statement after content change. Also I think editing small file in place is not so bad, espesialy if truncating after `write()` as I changed my example.

Comment: Hmm, I appreciate you trying to fix your answer, but you put the write before the truncate so the effect is the same. It is a very good idea to test your answers before posting them here, it protects against bugaboos like this.

Comment: Woop, nm that last comment, indeed this does work.  Well, we'll have to agree to disagree on whether or not this is a good idea :P